# PIC24 - multiple PWM duty cycle changes

Tags: pic, c

Apologies in advance due to my lack of experience with embedded C.

I am working on a [PIC24FJ64GA004](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026375) project in which a 16-bit PWM value need to be changed multiple times. I am using MPLAB IDE and C30.

I am wondering how I can change PWM values and where in code to change them. Is it a good idea to change PWM values in a timer ISR? In main()?

Comment: have you tried reading the datasheet?

Comment: Yes I understand some stuff from it. Also did some tutorial for practicing. But when I saw some codes for RGB using PWM they puzzled me alot. I am confuse now. I did one tutorial of PIC in which PWM changes at interrupt of timer. But most of the people for rgb changing PWM in different way. Which is difficult to understand.

Comment: I think your question will be better received if you cite specific things that are confusing you. As the question stands, it's very broad and difficult to answer.

Comment: @MZF786 I updated the 'look' of your question to better reflect how it should appear on this site; you probably need to add more details / clarify things per the above comments. Also, I don't think there's any such thing as a "pic24fj64da004" - I couldn't find any information on the Microchip website. I assumed you meant -GA, not -DA. Please correct if this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so broad that it will likely be closed soon, so I don't want to spend much time on this.

However, briefly, the main PWM "value" is its duty cycle.  This is changed by writing a different value into the appropriate duty cycle register.  To figure out what that is and what restrictions there might be, you have to look in the datasheet to see what peripherals your particular PIC has, then read about the PWM module in detail in the Family Reference Manual.  The datasheet will tell you which chapter is relevant for the particular implementation of the peripheral in your PIC.

There are two types of modules that can produce PWM outputs natively. The bare PWM modules are called "output compare".  There are also more fancy PWM modules meant for more specific applications.  These are generally called something with "PWM" in their names, like "motor control PWM" for example.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be whether it is better to update the PWM value in the interrupt handler or the main program.

Updating in the main program can potentially confuse the PWM logic. For example, if it is counting down to 0, and the main program reduces the PWM value to below the current count, for example, does the "value" comparator trigger when count = value? If so, you may get an unexpectedly short pulse and a temporary wrong output value. (Different micros may react differently; I don't know if this is an actual problem with the PIC; but the possibility is there).

So it may be better to synchronise the updates with the PWM counter; this is most easily done with a timer interrupt. Then the main program can generate a new value and set a flag, so that the next timer interrupt updates the PWM value in a safe manner, and clears the flag. (The flag can simply be the "new pwm value" variable not being 0).

This keeps most of the work out of the interrupt handler, which should usually be as short as possible.

Some of the examples you are studying may not bother going to such lengths; temporary errors in LED brightness probably don't matter!

Comment: Updating the duty cycle in a interrupt routine doesn't really fix the problem of updating it while in use.  Foreground code will update it randomly within a cycle, whereas interrupt code some reasonably repeatable offset from the start of a cycle.  One is not inherently better than the other.  If the PWM module has double buffered duty cycle registers, then it doesn't matter.  If not, then interrupt updates don't really fix anything.

Comment: There would be a certain minimum duty cycle below which interrupt updates would be problematic; I should have pointed that out.

Comment: Hi guys, I have looked in to data sheet of pic and find that it has feature of double buffer. So now do you guys think that I can set values in interrupt.